# Dashboard not being populated after data migration

Tags: commcare

After migrating data from an "old application (A)" to a new one (B), the Dashboard Feeds (case fed) created on the application B prior to the migration are not being populated with the data from the migration. 
However, when I create a new dashboard feed on B , I can see the migrated data.

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: Have you hit the "Update Data" button on the dashboard feed on HQ? Dashboard feeds only get updated once a day, so the changes may take a while to take effect.

Comment: Yes I tried updating using the "update data" but the issue is still the same!

Answer (score 1):

When data isn't appearing in your dashboard feeds, one thing to always check is the filters. One big "gotcha" is that the "End date" is set to when you created your dashboard feed and does not update. Thus, over time it will filter out more and more data as you modify and create more cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some items to check:

1. Your migration did not produce any data errors.
2. I would check the filters and dataflows on the original dashboard, could there be a conflict with a "modified date" field, or perhaps a unique key has been corrupted.
3. Check the data criteria on the original dashboard feeds to see if there is any constraint that is limiting the data used to the original "A" data.
4. You do not specify what tool is used to create the dashboards, but perhaps you need to edit the original dashboard feed (in some minor way) and resave that feed for it to pick up the new data. (Or if this is a browser dashboard, do you need to empty the cache?)